# Creating an ajax call to RoR controller

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, ruby-on-rails-5

I have a modal I need to render from a haml file - using rails MVC. The modal contains a button, and the button’s href has instance variables and I am not sure how to set them. When the controller calls render on this

The modal to be rendered:

```
.modal-body
= t('remittances.similar_refund_message', :transAm => @transAm, :EFTCheckDate => @EFTCheckDate)
=hidden_field_tag "action", @action
.footer.pull-right.padding-t-20
%a.btn.btn-primary{id:'save-refund-confirmation-button', href: update_refund_check_remittances_path(id: @remittance.id, payerName: @remittance.payer.name, checkDuplicate: false, filters: u/filters), 'data-remote'=>'true', type: 'button'}= t('remittances.yes_continue')
%a.btn{"data-dismiss" => "modal", type: "button"}= t('remittances.no_go_back')
```

The ruby controller action catching the ajax call:

```
def render_similar_update_refund_modal
    @action = params['actionType']
    @transAm = params['transAm']
    @EFTCheckDate = params['EFTCheckDate']
    render partial: 'similar_update_refund_modal_body'
end
```

The ajax call:

```
$.ajax({
url: errorModalUrl,
data: { actionType: actionType, transAm: transAmt, EFTCheckDate: EFTCheckDate }, success: function(response) {
$('.modal-body').replaceWith(response);
$('#remittance-error-button').click();
Terra.Overlay.hide();
},
```

I think my confusion is of how to use instance variables. I know that the remittance and filters variables are defined elsewhere in a function so I thought I could reference them.

This href works in the modal-body:

```
href: update_refund_check_remittances_path(checkDuplicate: false, isRefund: true)
```

Basically what I want is to have the button in the modal body contain the href that has those instance variables. This is done on the ***save button*** on the bottom of my form page and it works just fine. That save button acts like a form submission button but instead of submitting, it serializes the form data and sends it via Ajax to the controller which directs the data to the java back end for some mysql work. When I take the href from the save button and put it in the modal button, it fails and the ajax call (from clicking the modal button) immediately hits the error branch.

Are the instance variables just out of context, how can I pass that data in?

Comment: you want merge data on request ?

Comment: After further stepping through the debugger I realized I am not getting data to my view HAML for a modal. The debugger gets to where the instance variable is and stops. When I remove the instance variables it continues.

Comment: I can post more code later today. Is it possible to get the href from a button in another HAML and put it in the HAML I’m working on? I believe I read somewhere it strictly has to be done via controller.